# Update like rows based on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have several rows that I want to update based on like timestamps and user id.
So my data kind of looks like this

```
| INT(11) | TIMESTAMP        | VARCHAR(50) |
| user id | timestamp        | like id     |  
| 1       | 10/20/2014 10:30 |             |
| 1       | 10/20/2014 9:45  |             |  
| 1       | 10/20/2014 22:30 |             |
| 2       | 10/20/2014 9:45  |             |  
| 3       | 10/20/2014 10:30 |             |
| 3       | 10/20/2014 9:45  |             |
```

and I would like it to be updated like this where rows with the same user id and timestamp,
where timestamp matches if there is another entry within an hour (same day) in any other row with same user id.

```
| user id | timestamp        | like id |  
| 1       | 10/20/2014 10:30 | ASDF-1  |
| 1       | 10/20/2014 9:45  | ASDF-1  |
| 1       | 10/20/2014 11:30 | ASDF-1  |
| 1       | 10/20/2014 21:45 | ADGG-2  |   
| 1       | 10/20/2014 22:30 | ADGG-2  |
| 2       | 10/20/2014 9:45  | GFDQ-3  |  
| 3       | 10/20/2014 10:30 | QWER-4  |
| 3       | 10/20/2014 9:45  | QWER-4  |
```

is this possible to do within a MYSQL update statement? I haven't thought of a way to this yet.

EDIT: I would like to also generate a random 50char string for each of the grouped the like_ids

Comment: Is that a TIMESTAMP type column, or VARCHAR?

Comment: Please don't say you didn't use one of MySQL's column **designated to hold date and time values**.

Comment: I edited with the column types. Sorry yes, I am already using the TIMESTAMP column type for my timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SQL query that returns what you want:

```
select t.userid, t.timestamp,
       (@rn := if(@u = userid and @ts <= timestamp + interval 1 hour,
                  if(@ts := timestamp, @rn, @rn),
                  if(@u := userid, if(@ts := timestamp, @rn + 1, @rn + 1), @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as likeid
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @u := 0, @ts := 0) vars
order by userid, timestamp;
```

All the weird syntax with nested `if`s is to put the assignment of the variables into a single statement.

You can then use this for the update:

```
update t join
       (select t.userid, t.timestamp,
               (@rn := if(@u = userid and @ts <= timestamp + interval 1 hour,
                          if(@ts := timestamp, @rn, @rn),
                          if(@u := userid, if(@ts := timestamp, @rn + 1, @rn + 1), @rn + 1)
                         )
               ) as likeid
        from table t cross join
             (select @rn := 0, @u := 0, @ts := 0) vars
        order by userid, timestamp
       ) tnew
       on t.userid = tnew.userid and t.timestamp = tnew.timestamp
    set t.likeid = tnew.likeid;
```

Comment: Edit, sorry I added another requirement do you think you could modify to use a random string instead of incremental digits for the like_ids?

Comment: @DavePark . . . You should add that as another question, instead of modifying this question after it has been answered.  You can, however, use `rand()` with an argument to get a "random" float, where you can pick out any number of digits that you want.